# Global Variable Between Typescript Files?

Tags: typescript

I have 2 typescript files and I would like to share a global variable between each one.

I thought that since they are both in the same namespace it would be accessable but I am not able to access it.

```
file1.ts

namespace myFiles {
  var steps = [];
}

file2.ts

namespace myFiles {
  function getSteps() {
    console.log(steps, "steps");
  }
}
```

I looked at globalThis, but not sure how to really use it.

Comment: `export var steps = [];`?

Comment: You have to export and import it.